# Customize data annotations CompareAttribute

Tags: c#, properties, data-annotations

I need to compare two properties in a class using .net `data annotations`. One of the two properties should be filled and the other should be blank. How can I override the behavior of the `CompareAttribute` ? If it is not possible, what's the alternative solution ?

This class works with one issue:
If Property A is set to something and property B already has a value, then property A becomes invalid as expected. Upon Blanking property B, property A  should become valid but it won't until I try to modify property A so I trigger the validation again. Is there a way to connect the two together to trigger the validation on both one either one changes ?

```
 class CustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute
        {
        private readonly string _other;
        public CustomAttribute(string other)
            {
            _other = other;
            }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_other);
        if (property == null)
            {
            return new ValidationResult(
                string.Format("Unknown property: {0}", _other)
            );
            }
        var otherValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(otherValue.ToString()))
            {
              return new ValidationResult("Test");
            }
        return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the `CompareAttribute` with your own class:

```
public class CustomCompareAttribute: CompareAttribute {
    public CustomCompareAttribute(string otherProperty) : base(otherProperty) {
    }

   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {
       if (OtherProperty == null && value == null) {
            return new ValidationResult("Either A or B should be filled");
        }
        // more checks here ...
   }
}
```

Comment: How to force a data validation from setter ?

Comment: Anyone is able to help?

Comment: You can call the Validator manually like this: `object objectToValidate;  var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
                var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(objectToValidate, new ValidationContext(objectToValidate, null, null), validationResults, true);`

Comment: How is `OtherProperty` ever going to be `null`, it's not the value of the property it's the property name of the other property so this makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

For stuff like this I use [ExpressiveAnnotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations). It has a brilliant `RequiredIf` attribute:

```
[RequiredIf("B == null", ErrorMessage = "Either A or B should be filled")]
public string A { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("A == null", ErrorMessage = "Either A or B should be filled")]
public string B { get; set; }
```